# Send file to microservice using TCP transport layer?

Tags: tcp, graphql, upload, microservices, nest

Is it possible to send a file to a microservice using the TCP transport layer?
[image: in my graphql resolver]
[image: in my microservice client]
[image: in my controller]
and all I get in my microservice controller is

```
{
   filename: 'Screenshot_1.png',
   mimetype: 'image/png',
   encoding: '7bit'
 }
```

I tried different approach and all of them have failed.

Comment: I mean, basically all internet service protocols are based on TCP (http, ftp, ssh, grpc, SMTP...). So yes, the answer to your question is, yes that's possible. Was that **really** the question you've wanted to ask? Also, recommendation, do not try to reinvent the wheel. You want to push some JSON around. Use http/REST like the rest of the world, atop of an existing http implementation, not directly on TCP.

Comment: It is not clear what the requirements of this specific service are nor what the expected result is. You just dump code and result without context. *"I tried different approach and all of them have failed."* - which says exactly nothing what you actually tried, what you expected, what you got instead etc - i.e. this information is useless.